How can I hide some paper reviews from a given program chair in OpenReview, or at least make them anonymous to a given program chair?
4 OpenReview users include myself have access to the program chairs console of a venue in OpenReview, i.e. the venue has 4 program chairs in OpenReview. One of the program chair submitted a paper to that venue, so we'd like to hire reviews from them or at least make them anonymous. How can I hide some paper reviews from a given program chair in OpenReview, or at least make them anonymous to a given program chair?


One of the program chair submitted a paper to that venue, so we'd like to hire reviews from them or at least make them anonymous. How can I hide some paper reviews from a given program chair in OpenReview, or at least make  them anonymous.

Since the program chair is a co-author of that paper, then reviews are already anonymous to them (to prevent conflict of interest).
If the program chair is not a co-author of that paper, one can add custom conflict of interest: https://docs.openreview.net/how-to-guides/paper-matching-and-assignment/how-to-post-a-custom-conflict
Thanks to Yunyao Li for pointing me to that answer.
